# SDL2: libpng error: IDAT: chunk data is too large

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrWQsuDT3NE) on SDL2 for GameDev and I have run into this error while attempting to load PNG.
Here is my code:

```
void Game::Init(const char * title, int x_pos, int y_pos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen)
{
    int flags = 0;
    if (fullscreen) {
        flags = SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;
    }
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0) {
        std::cout << "Subsystems Initialized" << std::endl;
        window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, x_pos, y_pos, width, height, flags);
        if (window) {
            std::cout << "Window Created..." << std::endl;
        }
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
        if (renderer) {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
            std::cout << "Renderer Created..." << std::endl;
        }
        is_running = 1;
    }
    
    SDL_Surface * buf_surface = IMG_Load("assets/potato.png");
    std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    potato_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, buf_surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(buf_surface);
}
```

This is the error:
libpng error: IDAT: chunk data is too large
Error reading the PNG file.

Any suggestions?
PS this is my first time posting sorry if I did anything wrong.

Comment: This usually indicates simply a corrupted file. Try opening this file in an image editor, to see if it swallows it.

Comment: The file is fine and not corrupted it appears.

Comment: can you post your png?